# Action Script 3: Adding an gotoAndStop Animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, animation

So the other day I found a tutorial on how to create a pattern lock screen in action script. To do so I had to create a class, I have a good grasp on how the class is working. But I want to add an animation so when the user goes over the dots in the pattern and animation plays. But I have no idea how to do something like this through the class. Here is the code I used in my class.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.Strong;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var dots:Array = []; // Stores the in stage movieclips
        private var pattern:Array = []; //The pattern entered by the user
        private var pass:Array = [1,4,7,8,5,2,5]; //The correct pattern to proceed

        public function Main():void
        {
            dots = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine]; //add the clips in stage
            addListeners();
        }

        private function addListeners():void //adds the listeners to each dot
        {
            var dotsLength:int = dots.length;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < dotsLength; i++)
            {
                dots[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, initiatePattern);
                dots[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopPattern);
            }
        }

        /* Adds a mouse over listener and uses it to add the number of the dot to the pattern */

        private function initiatePattern(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var dotsLength:int = dots.length;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < dotsLength; i++)
            {
                dots[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, addPattern);
            }

            pattern.push(dots.indexOf(e.target) + 1); //adds the array index number of the clip plus one, because arrays are 0 based
        }

        private function addPattern(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            pattern.push(dots.indexOf(e.target) + 1); //adds the pattern on mouse over
        }

        private function stopPattern(e:MouseEvent):void //stops storing the pattern on mouse up
        {
            var dotsLength:int = dots.length;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < dotsLength; i++)
            {
                dots[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, addPattern);
            }

            checkPattern();
        }

        private function checkPattern():void //compares the patterns
        {
            var pLength:int = pass.length;
            var correct:int = 0;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < pLength; i++) //compares each number entered in the user array to the pass array
            {
                if (pass[i] == pattern[i])
                {
                    correct++;
                }
            }

            if (correct == pLength) //if the arrays match
            {
              //Hides Sign In
              MovieClip(root).LockScreen.visible = false;
              MovieClip(root).RTID.visible = false;
              MovieClip(root).SignIn.visible = false;
              //Turns On Main Menu
              MovieClip(root).gamemenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).biggamesmenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).totaltextmenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).tmenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).smenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).optionsmenu_mc.visible = true;
            }

            pattern = []; //clears the user array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean goes over? hover with the mouse?

Comment: By go over I mean when the user drags the mouse over the next dot. Your clicking in the mouse then dragging over your pattern. So I want to play an animation every time you drag over a dot

Comment: You want a mouseover animation of each dot?  Like the dot changing color or something?  Or you want the same animation to play regardless of the specific dot?

Comment: Same animation regardless the dot you go over. Right or wrong

Comment: As an aside, you don't need a class file to do this, putting this code on the first frame of timeline (and removing any private/public statements) would have the same result.

Comment: Agreed I know I didn't need a class but my code would have been way to long if I added this. The class is to keep my code neat and easy to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way I can think to do this is:

1. inside your dot movie clip, put a `stop()` action on the first frame
2. create your animation on the dot timeline and on the last frame of the animation put another `stop()`.
3. In your mouse over function, tell the dot to play.

   ```
   private function addPattern(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
       var dot:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
       if(dot.currentFrame < 2) dot.play(); //play only if on the first frame

       pattern.push(dots.indexOf(dot) + 1); //adds the pattern on mouse over
   }
   ```
4. Reset the dots animation

   ```
    private function stopPattern(e:MouseEvent):void //stops storing the pattern on mouse up
    {
       for (var i:int = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
       {
           dots[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, addPattern);
           dots[i].gotoAndStop(1); //go back to the first frame
       }

       checkPattern();
    }
   ```

Alternatively, if you're just want something simple like a layer of the dot fading in/out or the size of the dot increasing, you could just use a tweening library and tween the appropriate property on mouse over.

---

If you wanted to draw lines to connect the dots, you could do this:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.Strong;
    import flash.display.Shape;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

        private var lineContainer:Shape = new Shape();

        private var dots:Array = []; // Stores the in stage movieclips
        private var pattern:Array = []; //The pattern entered by the user //don't make life hard, just store the object itself instead of the index
        private var pass:Array;

        public function Main():void
        {
            dots = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine]; //add the clips in stage
            pass = [one,four,seven,eight,five,two,five]; //The correct pattern to proceed
            addChildAt(lineContainer, this.getChildIndex(one)); //the line container right behind the first dot.
            addListeners();
        }

        private function addListeners():void //adds the listeners to each dot
        {
            var dotsLength:int = dots.length;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < dotsLength; i++)
            {
                dots[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, initiatePattern);
                dots[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopPattern); //you could attach this to `this` instead of each dot, same result
            }
        }

        /* Adds a mouse over listener and uses it to add the number of the dot to the pattern */

        private function initiatePattern(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            pattern = []; //reset array
            lineContainer.graphics.clear(); //clear lines

            for (var i:int = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
            {
                dots[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, addPattern);
            }

                    addPattern(e); //trigger the mouse over for this element
        }

        private function addPattern(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //if (pattern.indexOf(e.currentTarget) == -1) { //wrap in this if statemnt if only wanted a dot to be selected once (like Android)
                pattern.push(e.currentTarget); //adds the pattern on mouse over
                drawLines();

                var dot:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
                if(dot.currentFrame < 2) dot.play(); //play only if on the first frame
            //}
        }

        private function drawLines():void {
            lineContainer.graphics.clear(); //clear the current lines
            lineContainer.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xFF0000); //thickness (5px) and color (red) of the lines

             if (pattern.length > 1) { //don't draw if there aren't at least two dots in the pattern
             lineContainer.graphics.moveTo(pattern[0].x + pattern[0].width * .5, pattern[0].y + pattern[0].height * .5); //move to first
         for (var i:int = 1; i < pattern.length; i++) {
        lineContainer.graphics.lineTo(pattern[i].x + pattern[i].width * .5, pattern[i].y + pattern[i].height * .5); //draw a line to the current dot
    }
          }

              lineContainer.graphics.endFill();

        }

        private function stopPattern(e:MouseEvent):void //stops storing the pattern on mouse up
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
            {
                dots[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, addPattern);
                dots[i].gotoAndStop(1); //go back to the first frame
            }

            checkPattern();
        }

        private function checkPattern():void //compares the patterns
        {
            var pLength:int = pass.length;
            var correct:int = 0;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < pLength; i++) //compares each number entered in the user array to the pass array
            {
                if (pass[i] == pattern[i])
                {
                    correct++;
                }
            }

            if (correct == pLength) //if the arrays match
            {
              //Hides Sign In
              MovieClip(root).LockScreen.visible = false;
              MovieClip(root).RTID.visible = false;
              MovieClip(root).SignIn.visible = false;
              //Turns On Main Menu
              MovieClip(root).gamemenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).biggamesmenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).totaltextmenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).tmenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).smenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).optionsmenu_mc.visible = true;
            }

            pattern = []; //clears the user array
            lineContainer.graphics.clear(); //clear the lines

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help I wanted to try out the line and see how it looks but im running int this error.  Type was not found or was not compile-time constant: Point.

Comment: Well i found the import for the library. But the line wont show up

Comment: Yea, I see a few error with my line drawing (I was just going off memory), I'll make a real example and update.

Comment: I added a container for the lines, because graphics objects are drawn below all other objects in the same parent. Which is likely why you weren't seeing them.  This assumes `one` is the back-most layer of all the dots.

Comment: I believe the privately scoped `lineContainer` variable should be declared inside the class. ;) Didn't want to edit it without your input/acknowledgement of the error.

Comment: @SlyRaskal  - Hilarious that no one notice that before now.  Good catch!