# Android like pattern lock AS3 and Flash CC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I found this post and it is exactly what I want, but I guess due to difference in Flash version, I am not able to get it to work. 
Post : [Action Script 3: Adding an gotoAndStop Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187669/action-script-3-adding-an-gotoandstop-animation/24189843#24189843?newreg=9f0bc06727c348cc9e510b7ee496ec54)

The error I get is: "

> 1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property
>   definitions."

This is for line where the declaration of lineContainer is done.

I tried declaraing it inside class but then I get the error stating :

> "The supplied display object must be child of caller".

I am quite newbee to flash and AS3, so I'm not able to solve this. I am using Flash CC. Any help would be great. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please attach a relevant part of your code

Comment: What you want to do + the 2 errors you are getting + the title of the question have absolutely nothing to do with each other. It's 4 questions in one, good luck with that.

Comment: Sorry for Not being clear... I wanted to do what the title is, i.e. create android pattern lock in AS3. The link I gave is to the post that claims to do the same. I used the same code but got the 1st error I mentioned

Comment: package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Shape;
   
    private var lineContainer:Shape = new Shape();  // *ERROR* 

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main():void
        {
            addChildAt(lineContainer, this.getChildIndex(one)); 
            addListeners();
        }

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the keyword `private` in the timeline. You can't declare global variables in the timeline. You're going to want to use classes.

Your second issue is with the line `this.getChildIndex(one)`. More than likely, `one` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in your comment (I fixed some missing curly braces):

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Shape;

    private var lineContainer:Shape = new Shape(); // ERROR

    public class Main extends Sprite { 

        public function Main():void
        {
            addChildAt(lineContainer, this.getChildIndex(one));
            addListeners();
        }

    }

}
```

And the error you are getting:

> 1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions."

It is because you have specified a `private` property outside of the `Main` class. In addition, the variable `one` is not declared anywhere in your class, so that should be throwing another error as well. You need to create a property or function variable named `one` set it however you need to, and then use it as a paramater to the `getChildIndex()` function calls

Instead you should do this:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Shape;

    public class Main extends Sprite { 

        private var lineContainer:Shape = new Shape();

        public function Main():void
        {
            addChildAt(lineContainer, this.getChildIndex(one));
            addListeners();
        }

    }

}
```

Try this and recompile and see what errors, if any you still receive.  Also be sure that this code is in a file named "Main.as".